# How to get values saved in strings from gridview editing event in grid view updating event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

On gridview editing event I have :

```
string name = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text;
string subname = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text;
```

I want to get those values from variables in row updating event gridview but I don't know how to access them.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`RowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.rowindex.aspx) property

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{    
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string name     = row.Cells[1].Text;
    string subname  = row.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

To get the old/new values of an updating row, you can also use the [`GridViewUpdateEventArgs.OldValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx) and [`GridViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) `Dictionaries`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{    
    string oldName     = e.OldValues["Name"]; 
    string oldSubname  = e.OldValues["SubName"];
    string newName     = e.NewValues["Name"];
    string newSubname  = e.NewValues["SubName"];
}
```

To detect only the changed values<strike>(not tested)</strike>:

```
var changed = new Dictionary<Object, Object>();
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
{
    if (e.OldValues[entry.Key] != entry.Value)
    {
        changed.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}
```

or with LINQ:

```
changed = e.NewValues.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
          .Where(entry => entry.Value != e.OldValues[entry.Key])
          .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx

Comment: thanks , another question : how to get the new value from cells instead of the old value? I need both old+new to add in a textbox like a history of what was changed. ty

Comment: @DanCristian: Edited, use the debugger to see how the dictionary entries are actually named.

Comment: What doesnt work? I have VS 2010. Do you get an error?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//The Name is string display on screen and name is variable used .
//The Subame is string display on screen and subname is variable used .

```
    Response.Write("The Name"+ name );
    Response.Write("The Subname" + subname);
}
```